# CodeIgniter version 2.1.4 cannot send email via smtp for office 365

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send email using SMTP server for office 365 using CodeIgniter version 2.1.4. I know the login is correct. Below are my config + debugger output.

application/config/email.php

```
<?php
  $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
  $config['smtp_host'] = 'tls://smtp.office365.com';
  $config['smtp_user'] = 'test@host.com';
  $config['smtp_pass'] = 'PASSWORD';
  $config['smtp_port'] = '587';
  $config['charset']='utf-8';
  $config['newline']="\r\n";
  $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
  ?>
```

Email debugger error:

```
The following SMTP error was encountered: 0 
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:
from: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:
to: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: DATA
data: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Mon, 6 Apr 2015 12:19:52 -0400 From: "PHP Point Of Sale, LLC" Return-Path: To: me@chrismuench.com Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Sales_Receipt?= Reply-To: "no-reply@phppointofsale.com" X-Sender: no-reply@phppointofsale.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID: <5522b228bf496@phppointofsale.com> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5522b228bf4b9" This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application may not support this format. --B_ALT_5522b228bf4b9 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit PHP Point Of Sale, LLC 123 Nowhere street 555-555-5555 Sales Receipt 04/06/2015 12:19 pm Customer: Chris Muench - Apple - 3333 Address : 6 Heron Way N Fairport NY, 14450-3318United States Phone Number : testE-Mail : me@chrismuench.comSale ID: POS 9 Register Name: Default Employee: John Doe Item Price Qty. Total TEST (Size) $12.00 1 $12.00   Sub Total $12.00 Total $12.00   Payment Type Cash $12.00   Change Due $0.00 Change return policy --B_ALT_5522b228bf4b9 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Comment: You should upgrade to Codeigniter 3.0 latest version

Comment: I'm not sure CI Email library supports the (TLS|SSL) connection requirements. You may need a library that can handle those transport types. http://getsparks.org/packages/swift-mailer/versions/HEAD/show

Comment: @mustang83 unfortunatly CI 3 just came out and requires a fair amount of code changes to get it to work. I am looking for a CI 2 fix.

Comment: if Ok past your controller code did you initialize the config

Comment: Setting `$config['smtp_crypto']` to `tls` and `$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.office365.com';` might work.

Comment: @karanthakkar that worked! Please post answer and I will accept. NOTE: the from header must be the same as smtp_user

Comment: thank you for the NOTE @ChrisMuench. I have posted it as answer. Glad that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though its not mentioned in [CI docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html)

There is a config item called `smtp_crypto` which you can find in `Email.php` class in your system libraries.
Which in your case needs to be set to `tls`.

So your config becomes

```
$config['smtp_crypto']= 'tls'; 
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.office365.com';
```